# Xpages: How to program a Drag and Drop a File Attachment in an Xpages to My Widgets

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpage that has instructions for users to get a widget into their Sidebar. I was going to send out the instructions in an email but I thought I should just embed it in an Xpage. Everything works, but I would like to have the file in the Xpage and have the users have the ability to drag and drop it right into My Widgets. I cannot see how to do this.

So far I have saved the file as a file resource. How can I connect that resource to a control in the Xpage?

Could I embed a view in the Xpage?

Or a Link?

```
    <xp:fileDownload rows="30" id="fileDownload1"
                        displayLastModified="false">

                    </xp:fileDownload>
                    <xp:link escape="true" text="Link" id="link1"
                        target="_blank">
                    </xp:link>
                </xp:td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a link to the file resource. Here's an example (assuming that your file resource is called widget.xml):

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="Link to widget" id="link1" value="/widget.xml"></xp:link>
```

The user should then be able to drag and drop that link to the My Widgets sidebar.

Comment: That is awesome, geez it is so easy. Do you have a blog or something. What country are you from, Germany, Holland?

Comment: I most certainly have a blog :-) See http://per.lausten.dk/blog/. I'm from Denmark as you can tell from my domain name.